# Send pong frame via WebSocket in javascript/NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I can't find any example of how I send a PONG response in javascript/NodeJS in regards to a WebSocket connection (back to a server which requires it - after it send a PING request)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you are using https://github.com/websockets/ws

Readme says:

> Pong messages are automatically sent in response to ping messages as required by the spec.